# Hover on div triggers div that will stay if hovered on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div that when it's hovered on, it will activate this other div. When the user moves his mouse on the activated div, I want that div to stay. Here is a snippet.

When you hover on the gold box, the purple box hides and the grey box is shown. Instead of disappearing, I want the grey box to stay when the mouse is over the grey box. And then when the mouse hovers over the gold box the second time, the grey box will hide itself, and the purple will return. How can I do this with smooth animations in Jquery?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#startMenu").hide();
  var timeoutId;
  $("#menuDesktop").hover(function() {
      if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
          timeoutId = null;
          $("#topBarDesktop").slideUp('400');
          $("#startMenu").slideDown('1000');
        }, 400);
      }
    },
    function() {
      if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;

      } else {
        $("#startMenu").slideUp('slow');
        $("#topBarDesktop").slideDown('400');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#topBarDesktop {
  position: fixed;
  top: -.1em;
  right: -1em;
  padding: 20px 100%;
  background: purple;
}
#menuDesktop {
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
}
#menuDesktop:hover {
  background: red;
}
#startMenu {
  background: grey;
  padding: 100% 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topBarDesktop">

</div>
<div id="menuDesktop">

</div>
<div id="startMenu">

</div>
```

Comment: use [$("#startMenu").slideToggle('1000');](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) in the hover event, that way it will remain open until you hover `$("#menuDesktop")` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `else` to and `else if` in order to check if `#startMenu` is hovered on or not. Then you'd also just want to make sure to call `.hover()` on both `#menuDesktop` and `#startMenu`, so that things slide back into place when you hover off of `#startMenu` as well.

```
$("#menuDesktop, #startMenu").hover(function() { //Added #startMenu to selector
  if (!timeoutId) {
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
      timeoutId = null;
      $("#topBarDesktop").slideUp('400');
      $("#startMenu").slideDown('1000');
    }, 400);
  }
}, function() {
  if (timeoutId) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = null;
  } else if ($("#startMenu:not(:hover)").length && $("#menuDesktop:not(:hover)").length) { //Checks that neither #startMenu or #menuDesktop is hovered on.
    $("#startMenu").slideUp('slow');
    $("#topBarDesktop").slideDown('400');
  }
});
```

Check out this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvthj74o/)

Comment: Thank you! That almost works, except I'd like it to toggle back when mouse is hovered on the gold box again. Id does though when I leave the page.

Comment: I added this on the end of the else if statement, why does it not work?     `&& $('#menuDesktopBtnClose').length`

Answer (score 0):

i have added few more lines to [Kld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1551411/kld) script

```
    $(function() {
  $("#startMenu").hide();
  var timeoutId;
  $("#menuDesktop").hover(function() {
     $("#menuDesktop").css("background", "red");
      if (!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
          timeoutId = null;
          $("#topBarDesktop").stop(true, true).slideUp('400');
          $("#startMenu").stop(true, true).slideDown('1000');
        }, 400);
      }
    },
    function() {
      if (timeoutId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;

      } else {
        $("#startMenu").stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
        $("#topBarDesktop").slideDown('400');
         $("#menuDesktop").css("background", "gold");
      }
    });

  $("#startMenu").hover(function(){
    $( this).stop();
       $("#topBarDesktop").stop(true, true);
       $("#menuDesktop").css("background", "red");
  }, function(){
     $("#startMenu").stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
     $("#topBarDesktop").slideDown('400');
     $("#menuDesktop").css("background", "gold");
  })       
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you make the grey box not disappear when the mouse moves quickly from the gold box to the grey?